# Ruby on Rails How to treat a error from a method call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling

I have this ruby code:

```
def get_last_quote(ticker)
  todays_date = Date.today
  data = YahooFinance::Scraper::Company.new(ticker.downcase).historical_prices(todays_date, todays_date)
  return data.first[:close]
end
```

When today's date is Sunday or Saturday I don't want any data, because markets are closed. Same thing happens on holidays or for any other day when the markets are closed.

So if it fails I want to subtract 1 from the days and check again, until I find a valid day.
The problem is that when the day is not valid I get Ruby on Rails error and I don't know how to treat it.

I tried:

```
while data.nil?
```

But it does not work, the error happens when I try to attribute the result to data, so I don't have a chance to check whether data is valid or not.

Any ideas, is it possible?

Comment: "Ruby on Rails error" do you mean exception. What is exception class?

Comment: Wrap the call to yahoo in a begin / rescue block and call the method with the new date in the rescue. Be sure to only rescue the exception that yahoo raises though so you don't blindly swallow other exceptions

Answer (score 0):

use `begin` then `rescue ErrorClass` with finally `end`

example

```
def method(args)
  args += 1
end

def call_method
  begin
    method(92929292)
  rescue ArgumentError, e
    e.message
  end
end
```